# Generating URL with Symfony Router component in PHPUnit test

Tags: unit-testing, symfony, testing, routes, phpunit

I am attempting to write a test in PHPUnit for a simple method which returns a URL based on a Symfony route for a subdomain. I'm not sure if my test has proper access to the Symfony Router component and that is why it is falling over, but I can't quite seem to get it to pass at the moment.

This is the error I am getting:

> There was 1 error:
>
> 1)
>   CRMPiccoBundle\Tests\Services\MailerHelperTest::testReturnsBillingURL
>   with data set "crmpicco.co.uk" (CRMPiccoBundle\Entity\Course Object
>   (...), 'https://www.crmpicco.co.uk/en/admin/billing') TypeError:
>   Return value of
>   CRMPiccoBundle\Services\MailerHelper::getBillingUrlForSubdomain() must
>   be of the type string, null returned

This is my test and data provider:

```
/**
 * @dataProvider dataProvider
 */
public function testReturnsBillingURL(Course $course, string $expectedUrl)
{
    $mailerHelper = new MailerHelper($this->getRouterMock());
    $this->assertEquals($expectedUrl, $mailerHelper->getBillingUrlForSubdomain($course, true));
}

public function dataProvider()
{
    return [
        'crmpicco.co.uk' => [
            'site' => (new Course())
                ->setSubdomain('crmpicco'),
            'expectedUrl' => 'https://www.crmpicco.co.uk/en/admin/billing',
        ],
    ];
}
```

This is my getRouterMock method:

```
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router
 */
protected function getRouterMock()
{
    return $this->getMockBuilder('\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router')
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->setMethods(['generate', 'supports', 'exists'])
        ->getMockForAbstractClass();
}
```

This is the method I am testing:

```
/**
 * @param Course $course
 * @param bool $absoluteUrl
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getBillingUrlForSubdomain(Course $course, bool $absoluteUrl = true) : string
{
    return $this->router->generate('crmpiccobundle_portal_billing', [
        'subdomain' => $site->getSubdomain(),
    ], $absoluteUrl);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you don't get a proper access to a Symfony Router, you're mocking it.
And in this mock, you don't define what to return on `generate()` method call, so no wonder it's returning `null`.

Your missing piece is

```
/**
 * @return \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router
 */
protected function getRouterMock()
{
    $mock = $this->getMockBuilder('\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router')
                 ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                 ->setMethods(['generate', 'supports', 'exists'])
                 ->getMockForAbstractClass();

    $args = ['crmpiccobundle_portal_billing', [
        'subdomain' => "crmpicco",
    ], true];

    $mock->expects($this->any())
         ->method('generate')
         ->withArgs($args)
         ->will($this->returnValue('https://www.crmpicco.co.uk/en/admin/billing'));

    return $mock;
}
```